# merge models octoberCMS, including attached files

Tags: laravel, merge, models, octobercms

How can I merge two models including attached files?

```
$hotels = collect([Hotel::get()]);
$tours = collect([Tours::get()]);
$merged = $hotels->merge($tours);
```

this works and merges collections, but it's doesnt include attacheOne/attachMany 
How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Two things.

Firstly, when you execute an `Eloquent` query, it returns a `Collection` instance automatically. You don't need to wrap the result inside a `Collection` yourself.

Second, to eager load model relations, you need to specify them using `with`.

E.g.

```
$hotels = Hotels::with('location', 'rooms')->get();
$tours = Tours::with('location')->get();
$merged = $hotels->merge($tours);
```

Comment: having a problem. for some reason method merge not working.
it only returns first collection. any ideas why?

Comment: $hotels = collect(Hotels::with('special_photo')->get();
$tours = collect(Tours::with('special_photo')->get();
$merged = $hotels->merge($tours);

working good. 
why?
thanks

Comment: The problem looks to be because Eloquent collections are indexed by the model key (id).

Comment: Yep, the use of model keys is going to cause one collection to overwrite the next where the ids clash. When you create a new support collection, the models are no longer indexed by ID when merging. Looks like you were right to do that originally.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't include relations because you haven't loaded any.

Rewrite it like this (replace the contents of `with(...)` with relations you want to load):

```
$hotels = Hotel::with(['relation1', 'relation2'])->get();
$tours = Tours::with(['relation1', 'relation2'])->get();

$merged = $hotels->merge($tours)->all();
```

Also results of model queries are automatically put in a collection, so you don't need to do the `collect(...)` part.